# Highlighted Reference does not work anymore for one file only

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

When I click on a reference, the word is not highlighted anymore.
In addition I can't navigate using CTRL-SHIFT-Down, or CTRL+Click.

**It actually happens only one one file in my solution!**

Does anyone faced this issue?

**Context**

Visual studio 2012

**Tried**
Restart VS several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fimally found the solution, right click => Properties on the file on the *Solution explorer*, for me the build action was set to *None*. Using Compile make it working as expected.

Thank your for your help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

gleng's last comment `Resharper > Options > Environment > Keyboard & Menus > Select Visual Studio and Apply Scheme` should work.

If it still doesn't work, Go to the following folder and delete the Resharper's cache for the project.

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\ReSharper\
```

For example,

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\JetBrains\ReSharper\v8.0\SolutionCaches
```

Comment: Did the manipulation and restarted, still the same issue.
But I don't think it is link to Resharper as it works for all other files.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this happen a couple times and was able to solve by doing this:

> Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> General -> Clear Caches

And/or:

> Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard & Menus -> Reapply
>   Visual Studio Theme

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but did not worked for me.
As far as I know this functionality was not from Resharper, no?

Comment: @Thomas What about Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard & Menus -> and reapply visual studio theme?